# OpenLayers Map with custom SRS (without EPSG code)

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

Is it possible to show geodata by OpenLayers in custom projection?

I want to show my geodata in OpenLayers interface.

Source layer(s):  shapefile(s), standard [epsg:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) lat/lon projection; processed by MapServer (WMS Layers).

Result map: Albers Conic Equal Area projection, with specific central meridian (it has no EPSG code).

Definition in PROJ.4 format:

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=52 +lat_2=64 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=93 +x_0=16500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +towgs84=28,-130,-95,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

As to MapServer Layers – they are all well, I can show geodata through standard MapServer CGI template-based interface, in this custom Albers projection…

For OpenLayers I tried to define Proj4js.defs –

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol/style.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #mouse-position-meters,
    #mouse-position-4326 {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
    #shortdesc {
        margin-bottom: .5em;
        clear: left;
    }
</style>
<script src="lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Proj4js.defs["USER:00001"] = "+proj=aea +lat_1=52 +lat_2=64 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=93 +x_0=16500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +towgs84=28,-130,-95,0,0,0,0 +no_defs";
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: 'USER:00001',
        maxResolution: 'auto',
        units: 'm',
        controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),    
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                div: $('mouse-position-meters'),
                prefix: 'Coords: (',
                suffix: ') m (ALBERS).'
            }),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                div: $('mouse-position-4326'),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
                prefix: 'Coords: (',
                suffix: ') dd (EPSG:4326).'
            })
        ],
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(12460000, 4870000, 20540000, 9500000)
    });
    var rus_general = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer('Russian Regions', 
        'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe',
    {map: 'C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/test/z-albers.map', layers: 'rus_general'}
        );
    map.addLayer(rus_general);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1 id="title">OpenLayers Test</h1>
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
<div id="mouse-position-meters"></div>
<div id="mouse-position-4326"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the presented coordinate transformation works correctly (displaying the appropriate numbers when I move the mouse), but the map does not appear…

How can I do this?

**Discussion of the problem & Answer to the question --**
It looks like I found the answer myself...  The above source code has been corrected, and already has a working version

I changed WMS-layer upon layer of MapServer type

Original (non-working) version was:

```
...
    var rus_general = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 'Russian Regions', 
        'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/test/z-albers.map', 
    {layers: 'rus_general'}
        );
...
```

In this case, the bottleneck - WMS-service: I do not know how to specify a custom (non-EPSG) projection in this case...

This is not a problem for the MapServer layer type. MapServer generates a map projection with PROJECTION section in the MAP-file. There are no restrictions such as "EPSG Only"...

Comment: Is this your full code? I don't see where you add a single base or overlay layer.

Comment: No, it is only part of the code ..

Comment: You shoul add your custom projection to epg file. Open your epsg file in a text editor and edit it. On Windows, the default location of the epsg file is c:\proj\nad. MS4W users will find the epsg file in \ms4w\proj\nad.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: I had a similar problem earlier on however I was able to get around it by adding a custom projection using proj4js available here; http://wwww.proj4js.org/ load it into your project like so; <script src="js/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script> then define the custom projection like so (thats if you have the custom formula definition) in my own case;  proj4.defs([
            [
              'EPSG:26910',
              '+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'
            ]]);  Where "EPSG:26910" is the custom identifier for your projection

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems right. you have included proj4js because it is needed for projections other than 900913 and 4326 but, where is the OpenLayers.Layer.WMS pointing to your WMS server?

---

[OpenLayers Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-create-gis-web-applications-cookbook/book) can help you

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am very detail overlooked this book. Unfortunately, there does not discuss details on the custom projections...
 
I really just gave a code snippet. Details are provided below.